# Interrupting a loop mid run, with GUI control

Tags: python

I'm currently using pygtk and glade to create a program that will control a voltage sweep between two voltages.

I was wondering how it would be possible to interrupt the sweep as a safety feature if something happened to go wrong with the output. I have posted my sweep code below. Essentially what I would like is a function that connects to a "stop" button which I can insert into my script without having to run a sys.exit() and close out of the GUI or the program.

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while min(start, stop) <= r <= max(start, stop):
        yield r
        r = r + step

def setchan(self, widget, N, v_f=None):
    delay = float(self.delayer.get_text())/1000
    if (v_f == None): float( self.volt_widgets[int(N-1)][0].get_text())
    self.min = float( self.volt_widgets[int(N-1)][1].get_text())
    self.max = float( self.volt_widgets[int(N-1)][2].get_text())
    if v_f > self.max:
        print "The channel voltage would be set to more than the allowed maximum"
        raise ValueError
    if v_f < self.min:
        print "The channel voltage would be set to less than the allowed minimum"
        raise ValueError
    v_f = self.translate_Vf_to_Vb(self.poldacs[int(N-1)], v_f)
    self.device.do_set_dac( v_f, N )

def sweepchan(self, widget, N):
    self.get_pol()
    delay = float(self.delayer.get_text())/1000
    numstep = int(self.stepper.get_text())
    v_i = self.translate_Vb_to_Vf(self.poldacs[N-1], self.device.do_get_dac(N))
    v_f = float( self.volt_widgets[int(N-1)][0].get_text())
    self.min = float( self.volt_widgets[int(N-1)][1].get_text())
    self.max = float( self.volt_widgets[int(N-1)][2].get_text())

    if v_f > self.max:
        print "The final voltage is set to higher than the allowed maximum"
        return
    if v_f < self.min:
        print "The final voltage is set to less than the allowed minimum"
        return

    vstep = (v_f - v_i)/numstep
    if abs(vstep) <= 0.00001:
        print "The current voltage and final voltage are the same"
        return
    for V in drange(v_i, v_f, vstep):
        self.setchan( None, N, V)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Does the code run in the main or in a separate thread?